# How to reset text field after form submitted in DATABASE(with target iframe)

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with target iframe. I want to reset the field after form is done submitting/data inserted to database

Thanks in advance!

```
                    <form method="POST" name="chatform" autocomplete="off" target="iframe">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="chat" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="submit btn btn-info btn-sm" name="send">
                                    <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>

                    <iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: If form submited means field will become empty automatically . Then what's wrong ?

Comment: nope. the field wont be empty because it has target iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" id="frame" name="chatform" autocomplete="off" target="iframe">

</form>                                           

<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" name="iframe" onload="parent.document.getElementById('frame').reset();"></iframe>
```

I use onload in iframe to reset the text field :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) for a clean solution.

`<form method="POST" name="chatform" autocomplete="off" target="iframe"    onsubmit="this.reset();">`

Comment: it reset the field but it wont let the content insert to the database

Comment: Append a `<?php
if(isset($_POST["chat"]))
 echo $_POST["chat"];`
to your form, so you can be sure your data gets transmitted. The problem probably is somewhere else.

Comment: I have code `<?php if(isset['send'0]){ if(empty($chat)) { echo "<script>alert('Chat is empty')</script>"; } else{` it will insert to databse. and it always say chat is empty. so it means the form is reset before it will insert to database

Comment: You're missing something. [link](http://main.xfiddle.com/code_65640986.php)

Comment: if (isset($_POST['send'])) 
    {
     etc.......code

      if(empty($chat)) {
          echo "<script>alert('Chat is empty')</script>";
      }
      else{

      $select = $conn->query("SELECT * from admin where USERNAME = '$user'");
      while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
            $pic = $rows['PICTURE'];
            $uid = $rows['ID'];

      $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO chat () VALUES ('','$uid','$user','$chat','$date','$pic')");
      }
      }
    }
}

Comment: You used `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` in  a previous comment. Maybe thats your problem.

Comment: mysqli_real_scape_string wont work. so i use my sql. still got the same problem when I use mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript

```
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="return formSubmit()" id="frame" ....


 <script>
   $("#frame").reset();
   return true;
</script>
```

It will reset just before submit.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer I'll try this :D